# AndroidTestCase fails to find resource of test project when executed via maven

Tags: android, maven, testing

I have an android project with test cases written using AndroidTestCase and ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Until now I have been executing them via 'ant' thus:
ant clean emma debug install test
and also from inside IntelliJ, with no problem (once I used the correct context in the tests code each time).

I have recently mavenized my project with the android-maven-plugin.

Now, some of my test cases (AndroidTestCase) fail as they fail to find some resources (e.g. a string, or a style) that is defined in the test project.

I am aware of the two contexts and possible issues there, but this seems different.
The resource is defined in my test project, it shows up in R.java in test project (target/generated-sources), and in my test case I refer to it using the package name of the test project where it is defined, and using the test context.

I have tried using mContext, and also getContext() without success, and the test fails with a:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f05001c
```

And that integer matches the one in the generated R.java in my test project. 
A resource of the same name (neither package nor resource name) does NOT exist in the app under test, only in the test app.

I have tried specifying the packageName in the pom.xml, with no difference.

I don´t understand how I can use the symbol for the R of the test project, and use the context of the test project, and not find the resource defined in the test project.

UPDATE:
If I convert the AndroidTestCase into a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and then use getInstrumentation().getContext().getResource(), then it works, however when I want the Target app context (using getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()) it causes problems for units under test as they cannot access the context of the app.

So, it seems that when running the tests via the android-maven-plugin there is some difference in how the test app is run.

Comment: I have opened an Issue in the maven android plugin project here: https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=460 after testing it with a fork of the samples project here https://github.com/andrewdavidmackenzie/maven-android-plugin-samples